# ASP.net Razor app: Using Bootstrap, CSS or JS, is there an easy way to move an entire table column left and right? Reorder the columns on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have requirements to take a HTML table and dynamically move the columns when the user clicks a left/right caret on the column header.
Is this impossible? Feels like a big lift.
I would appreciate any pointers implementing this functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic method to loop through each cell and move it in front of the previous cell.

There's very likely a fancier/shorter way to do this, but knowing a basic method can always help you understand/develop the fancier methods.

Breakdown:

```
$("table>thead>tr,table>tbody>tr").each
```

loop through both thead and tbody, could also do `$("table tr")` but that may not work if you have nested tables

```
$(this).find("th,td").eq(2).each(
```

Here `this` is the `tr` from the previous `each`, find child `th` and `td` then only the 3rd column (0-based).

```
$(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
```

now `this` is the th/td from the previous `each`, take this cell (3rd column) and move it in front of the previous cell.

Snippet:

```js
$("button").click(() =>
  $("table>thead>tr,table>tbody>tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("th,td").eq(2).each(function() {
      $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
    });
  })
);
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
      <th>col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1 1</td>
      <td>cell 1 2</td>
      <td>cell 1 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 2 1</td>
      <td>cell 2 2</td>
      <td>cell 2 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type='button' id='clickme'>click me</button>
```